# Identify a short story about a man and his robot household helper

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I don't remember the Title or the Author of the story I read around 10 years ago (2000s), but it goes like this:

A single man lived alone in his house and so had to spend a lot of time maintaining it. One day, he either sees an advertisement about robot helpers or is told about it by his friend, and decides to get one. 
Initially, the robot is very efficient in maintaining the house, but over-time, his efficiency begins to degrade, with his parts falling off, and then the man decides to take care of his robot rather than throwing it away.

Comment: Do you remember when you may have read it? Whether it was part of an anthology, what the anthology may have been called?

Comment: Yes, it was part of an anthology, but I don't recall the name.

Comment: When you may have read it? When it was published? The theme of the anthology?

Comment: Around 10 years ago, but the anthology didn't have a common theme in its stories afaik. I also can't recall the publishing date

Comment: Did it seem like an old book when you'd read it? Or quite new?

Comment: It didn't exactly feel old or new at the time